# Does Connection.__exit__ close itself in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, with-statement

I use to open SQL connections using `with` statements, like this

```py
with sqlite3.connect('data.db') as con:
    # do something here
```

I supposed that a connection closes itself on an exit from the `with` block, just like files do, but now I have some doubts about this. I looked through [Connection class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects) documentation, but didn't find any clue. Does anybody know for sure what exactly `Connection.__exit__` does? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it [commits or rolls back](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager). It doesn't close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it [doesn't close the connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

```
# Connection object used as context manager only commits or rollbacks transactions,
# so the connection object should be closed manually
con.close()
```

Using the connection as a context manager will commit or roll back.

If you want to automatically close as well you could use the [**`contextlib.closing`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(sqlite3.connect('data.db')) as con:
    with con:
        # do something here
```

You need the second `with`.

Comment: Just to note, I think you need to use `with` twice.

Answer (score 0):

When using then [contextlib.closing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager you can do the following without nesting the second `with` as per [this discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/implicitly-close-sqlite3-connections-with-context-managers/33320/6). I've tested it and it works:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(sqlite3.connect('data.db')) as con, con:
    # do something here
```